# Data fetched from mysql is displayed 2 times

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am new to php. I want to fetch a particular data from mysql and display it in the label.I have tried a simple php coding.But it displays the fetched data two times(actually I have created 2 columns such as name and age in a table called test).Please help me.Here is the coding:

displayform.php

```
<body>
 <form method="post" name="display" action="display.php" >
 Enter the name you like to display the data from MySQL:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="display" /> </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

display.php

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Connection Failed");
 mysql_select_db("acp")or die("Connection Failed"); 
 $name = $_POST['name']; 
 $query = "select age from test where name = '$name'";
  $result = mysql_query($query); 
  while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
  { 
  echo $line['age'];
   echo "<br>\n"; 
   } 
?>
```

The datas in table is

```
name=janani
age=25
```

The output is displayed as

```
25
25
```

Comment: Are you sure that there is only one `janani` in `test` table?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have duplicated data? If so, add `LIMIT 1` and/or `DISTINCT` to your query.

Comment: use echo mysql_num_rows($result); and find the result num of rows..As a stater you should not blindly depend on result..follow the procedure and see num of rows you are getting

Comment: You might have **janani** name two times.Because code is working perfecty fine.Check your database.

Answer (score 1):

I am certain that you have two rows bearing the same name and/or age.

In order to show only one result, what you need to do is:

- Use either `DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY`, or `LIMIT 1`.

I.e.:

```
$query = "select DISTINCT age from test where name = '$name' GROUP BY name";
```

or

```
$query = "select age from test where name = '$name' LIMIT 1";
```

---

***Sidenote:*** I suggest you use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) though, since your code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).

```
<?php

$DB_HOST = "xxx"; // Replace
$DB_NAME = "xxx"; // with
$DB_USER = "xxx"; // your
$DB_PASS = "xxx"; // credentials

$conn = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($conn->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $conn->connect_error . ']');
}

if($statement=$conn->prepare("select age from test where name = ? LIMIT 1")){

// or this one
// if($statement=$conn->prepare("select distinct age from test where name = ? group by name")){

$name = "janani";

 $statement-> bind_param("s", $name);

// Execute
 $statement-> execute();

// Bind results
 $statement-> bind_result($age);

// Fetch value
 while ( $statement-> fetch() ) {
 echo $age . "<br>";
 }

// Close statement
 $statement-> close();
 }

// Close entire connection
 $conn-> close();
```

Answer (score 0):

$line = mysql_fetch_array($result) ; //remove while loop

echo $line['age'][0];

try this ans this is work for one data fetch from table .. And may possible  your result show two time because $name match two times in table so it fetch two record

Comment: This only works if he has a single row in the result. What if he is trying to display multiple lines (aside the duplication he reports, which should be fixed)?

Comment: @simone yup I mention that .i think user query is right otherwise

Answer (score 0):

You are hard coding 'age' in the array reference so it will echo that element only. Loop over array by index and you will get the name also.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the data is shown two times.